# Emulate a "alert" or "prompt" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt

I'm aware of the principles behind event driven programming but would nevertheless try to better understand if and how it is possible to emulate the functionality of the native alert or prompt functions in JavaScript.
Clearly the point is the blocking behavior of those native functions and how this could be emulated in JavaScript.

Comment: Asynchronous behaviour? They are both blocking. In fact, how could a prompt not be blocking, if it must way for user's response?

Comment: it's not that clear for me, could you elaborate more, give us some use case. and do you want to do the exact same thing as the native alert/prompt?

Comment: `alert` and `prompt` are anything but asynchronous... Implementing something similar is actually a lot of work, and not trivial (i.e. nothing that an SO answer is appropriate for) - start coding it and make a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry for the wrongly writing asynchronous instead of blocking! I'm looking for a BLOCKING solution that emulates the blocking behavior of the native alert or prompt functions.

Comment: I have no facts to present to support this, but my gut feeling says that for security reasons the browser won't let scripts halt the entire JS engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use twitters bootstrap - modal:
twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

or jquerys ui - modal: jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

both are non blocking

//edit:
this? https://github.com/malsup/blockui/blob/master/jquery.blockUI.js && http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

Comment: and if ur interested how it all works: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js
or https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js

Comment: Thank you for the link but I'm actually looking to understand how to implement a blocking solution like the native one.